# Robocopy logs of each day in a separate text file?

Tags: windows, log-files, replication, robocopy, mirroring

I'm using the batch file below:

```
@echo
 for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
  set _date=%%a%%b%%c
  )
robocopy D:\a D:\b /mir /mot:1 /log:"d:\logs\%_date%.txt"
exit
```

But it creates a single file.

I'd want robocopy logs of each day in a separate text file , named with the current date.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a lot easier if you did it in powershell.

```
$date = Get-Date -format yyyyMd

robocopy D:\a D:\b /mir /mot:1 /log:$date.txt
```

Is there a reason you can't use powershell?

Comment: no i can use powershell as well. replication is real time and i want logs file , which gives me information of one day in one file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing, but using a Robocopy job file (*.rcj).  To solve the original, simply add at the command line `/LOG+:%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:4,2%.txt` - this will give you a `20191023.txt` output and change as the date changes. Doesn't work on `.RCJ` files though.

Comment: Using %DATE% interactively in a command prompt worked, but not when running Robocopy in a scheduled task.  I changed the scheduled task action to 'cmd /c robocopy ...', and then it worked.  It's about accessing environment variables I think.  Perhaps something to test with the .RCJ?